# Matlab - 2D Low Band Power Calculation for a Region inside an Image

Tags: matlab, low-bandwidth

I have to calculate the "Low Band Power" for a region (not always rectangular) inside an Image. I have to do this because I have to implement the algorithm explained in this [paper](http://www.4shared.com/web/preview/pdf/wox7Z_HKba?) (see page 2 in the paragraph "Fire Detection Algorithms") using Matlab. So my questions are:

**How can I calculate the Low Band Power?**

The idea is to follow this three steps:

- FI = Calculation of the 2D Fourier Transform with fft2
- LBFI = Make 0 all value outside a circle (low band pass)
- PSD = Calculation of the Power

In code

```
FI = fftshift(fft2(img));
LBFI = % not yet done
PSD = sum(sum(abs(LBFI).^2))
```

**Is there a way to adapt this algoritm for a not rectangular region?**

I think that there's no way to make something similar but I hope to be wrong